# C# dynamic object - setting "Enum" value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have a dynamic object (C# 4.0), In that i want to set an Enum value for a property dynamically, But i do not have an assembly reference for that type. Any idea on how to do this / is it possible to do this ?

```
dynamic vehicle = myObject;
vehicle.AddTires(); // working
vehicle.ConfigureEngine(); //working
vehicle.seat="Leather";//working
//Enum needs to be set for the Make
vehicle.Make = Manufacturer.Toyota; // how to do this?
```

Comment: eh, assembly reference for _what_ type?

Comment: I believe he means, he doesnt have a reference to Manufacturer

Comment: Yes i do not have reference to "Manufacturer"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `c.Make` always has a value (e.g. its type is `Manufacturer`, not `Manufacturer?` or the property doesn't exist at all before you set it):

```
c.Make = Enum.Parse(c.Make.GetType(), "Toyota");
```

If this won't work for you as-is, to use this approach, you'll need to somehow get a reference to the type `Manufacturer`.  How complex this might be depends on how your dynamic type is set up.  Another approach (e.g. if it's `Manufacturer?` and might be null) you might need to take is to use reflection to get the `Make` property to find what type it is.

Comment: I just tried this, and it seems to be the only way I can get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.Parse()` has a return type of `object`, however, you can cast the returned object to `dynamic` to force it to look at the actual runtime type.

```
vehicle.Make = (dynamic)Enum.Parse(vehicle.Make.GetType(), "Toyota");
```